# Dewalt Power Drill DEWALT DCD708B, how to change drill bit

Tags: tools, drill, powertools

I have a Dewalt Power Drill DEWALT [DCD708B ATOMIC](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DEWALT-ATOMIC-20-Volt-MAX-Cordless-Brushless-Compact-1-2-in-Drill-Driver-2-20-Volt-1-3Ah-Batteries-Charger-Bag-DCD708C2/308067442#overlay).  Instruction manual [here](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/9f/9f36dc1a-2313-4520-8348-d76761b531f5.pdf).

What is the proper way to change a drill bit? I see many online videos, where they remove the battery, open the chuck hole manully with hand, and then retwist to tighten manually. In other articles, they use the battery to automatically open, and then auto retighten with the trigger. For my particular drill, it does not mention in the directions, and trying to figure out.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entirely up to you. Manufacturers need to write instructions which put them totally in the clear so even fully paid up idiots cannot sue them.

I've changed bits on drills for several decades using the rotation from the motor, with no problems. But it would only need a bit of swarf on the chuck to make me think again. Wearing gloves would probably remove that threat. As with all power tools, exercise caution, and weigh up advantages/disadvantages of how to perform certain operations, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if most tradesmen didn't do it my way!

Comment: Be _very_ cautious about using gloves with power tools. Getting the glove caught in the rotating tool can pull your hand into the tool and cause severe damage. TBH, this is _exactly_ the way I've done it for _year_, and I've never had issues. I've even done it with gloves on. However, it's worth noting the danger of gloves with power tools, especially as the OP seems to be a beginner. Saws are significantly more dangerous with gloves, but drills can still get you.

Comment: Erm... that was supposed to read "this is exactly the way I've done it for _years_" plural, not singular. I almost always use the motor to spin the chuck while holding the collar to tighten/loosen it.

Answer (score 5):

Hold the drill in one hand and tighten the chuck using its collar with the other.

Sometimes people open or close the jaws using power ie the motor as it is quicker.

Some will even tighten against motor power but if you have weak wrists you may regret that.

Comment: Every drill maker says not to use power when tightening or removing.  Every drill user says it takes too long by hand.  No drill user can sue maker when their hand gets caught on a spinning chuck.

Comment: @crip659 As I said "some will  even tighten against motor power". I don't state that the manufacturer states that it is ok or safe. Lots of things are stated in instructions ythat get ignored, in fact, how many even read all the instructions provided?

Comment: Instructions are read to see what all the left over pieces are for.

Comment: hi @crip659 feel free to write another answer, and I can send points to both of you, thanks, I have seen both answers on youtube